# Difficulty with Drag and Drop

Tags: swift, macos

I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement simple drag and drop in a macOS application. What I want to do is make a TextField that can accept a directory or file that is dropped onto it and capture the URL to that directory or file.

With the code shown below, my `print("dragging entered")` line does fire when I drag an object onto the TextField control, however when I release it the `performDragOperation` doesn't fire.

Can anyone please help me understand simple drag and drop?

Thanks

import Cocoa

```
class DropTextField: NSTextField {

    var dragTypes : [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType] = [.fileURL, .URL]

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.registerForDraggedTypes(dragTypes)
    }
    
    public override func prepareForDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    public override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        print("dragging engtered")
        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }
    
    
    public override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        print("drag operation")
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Explain, only if you like, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to be able to drag a file or directory onto a TextField and display it's url (as well as take that url for further processing of the item or items in the directory of the url.)

Comment: Why are you sub-classing `NSTextField`, then?  You should sub-class `NSView`.  Lay it underneath your text field.

Comment: I'm sure the reason I'm trying to do it this way is because of my lack of understanding of how this works.

I thought that if I wanted to give drag and drop functionality to the control I would need to subclass, then build that functionality into my version of it. (Also, even if it's wrong to do it this way, why is it not working?)

I appreciate the help and advice.

Comment: Oh, and another reason I thought to try to do it this way was because I have more than one TextField in my window and I needed each TextField to represent a different directory dropped on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this custom class to the `NSTextField` object on the storyboard and create an outlet in the controller:

```
public class DragTextField: NSTextField {
    
    public var completionHandler: (URL) -> Void = { fileURL in Swift.print(fileURL) }
    
    public override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation { return NSDragOperation.copy }
    public override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation { return NSDragOperation.copy }
    public override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        let pboard = sender.draggingPasteboard
        
        if let fileURLFromClipboard = pboard.string(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL) {
            
            let sourceFileURL = URL(string: fileURLFromClipboard)!
            print(sourceFileURL)
            completionHandler(sourceFileURL)
        }
        return true
    }
    
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        stringValue = "Drop File Here";
        isEditable = false
        wantsLayer = true;
        layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        
        // Register for file name drag
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dropView: DragTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dropView.completionHandler = {
            print("File Path:  \($0)")
        }
    }
}
```